# In ReactJS, how can I best organize my code when iterating over non-shallow data structures

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I'm using React and I have the following data structure:

```
[
  {
    key: 'test'
    data: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'test name',
        desc: 'aaaaaaaaa'
      },
      {
       id: 2,
       name: 'test name2',
       desc: 'aaaaaaaaa'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'test name3',
        desc: 'aaaaaaaaa'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    key: 'test2'
    data: [
      {
        id: 5,
        name: 'test name5',
        desc: 'aaaaaaaaa'
      },
      {
       id: 5,
       name: 'test name2',
       desc: 'aaaaaaaaa'
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        name: 'test name6',
        desc: 'aaaaaaaaa'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I'm looking for a better way of fetching data from such a structure. The thing is that is should be one `ul` list with `li` items inside.

I have such a structure for this:

```
<div className='wrapper'}>
  {tabInfo.map(({key, data}) => {
    return (
    <div className='tab-list' key={key}>                  
      <h4>{key}</h4>                  
      <ul>
        {data.map(({id, name, desc}) => {
          return (
            <li key={id}>
              <span className='name'>
                {name}
              </span>
              <span className="desc">{desc}</span>
            </li>
          )
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
    )
  })}
</div>
```

What is the better way of fetching the data in such a case? I think `map` inside `map` isn't good idea.

Comment: What is the question? Are you looking for a code review? Does this work? `What is the better way of fetching the data in such a case` fetching the data from where?

Comment: You could separate the function handling the `data.map`. You could make it a separate component, even.

Comment: *"I think map inside map isn't good idea."* Why not? That's exactly what you're doing, mapping the entries from `data` to `li` elements.

Comment: Yes I would like to make code better

Comment: I find this completely fine. You could even do as @OliverRadini mentioned.

Comment: @OliverRadini could you please provide some example what do you mean?

Comment: @rick1 I've added an answer now, it's fairly short though, and I haven't tested it, as the actual changes required here are pretty minimal

Comment: Based on the structure of the data you said you're fetching, I think it's completely fine. You could make the second map return a separate component for clarity sake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this will do it, though I haven't tested this to be sure. You can move this to a separate component which can then be used as part of the map:

```
const ListItem = ({ id, name, desc }) => (
    <li key={id}>
        <span className='name'>
            {name}
        </span>
        <span className="desc">
            {desc}
        </span>
    </li>
);

<div className='wrapper'}>
    {tabInfo.map(({key, data}) => {
        return (
            <div className='tab-list' key={key}>
                <h4>{key}</h4>
                <ul>
                {data.map(dataItem => <ListItem {...dataItem} />)}
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    })}
</div>
```

I may have missed something here, so if there are any problems, I'd be happy to know about the,m so I can fix this up